# Load balancer and WebSockets

Tags: websocket, socket.io, signalr, load-balancing, f5

Our infrastructure is composed by

- 1 F5 load balancer
- 3 nodes

We have an application which uses websockets, so when a user goes to our site, it opens a websocket to the balancer which it connects to the first available node, and it works as expected.

Our truobles arrives with maintenance tasks, when we have to update our software, we need to turn offline 1 node at a time, deploy the new release and then turn it on again. Doing this task, **the balancer drops the open websocket connections to the node and the clients retries to connect after few seconds** to the first available nodes, creating an inconvenience for the client because he could miss a signal (or more).

How we can keep the connection between the client and the balancer, changing the backend websocket server? Is the load balancer enough to achieve our goal or we need to change our infrastructure?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this kind of problems I recommend to read about the [Azure SignalR](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-pt/services/signalr-service/). With this you don't need to thing about stuff like load balancer, redis backplane and other infrastructures that you possibly need to a `WebSockets` connection.

Basically the clients will not connected to your node directly but redirected to Azure SignalR. You can read more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-overview

Since it is important to your application to maintain the connection, I don't see how any other way to archive no connection drop to your nodes, since you need to shut them down.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to understand that the F5 is a full TCP proxy. This means that the F5 is the server to the client and the client to the server. If you are using the websockets protocol then you **must** apply a websockets profile to the F5 Virtual Server in order for the websockets application to be handled properly by the Load Balancer.

Details of the websockets profile can be found here: https://support.f5.com/csp/article/K14754

If a websockets and an HTTP profile are applied to the Virtual Server - meaning that you have websockets and web traffic using the same port and LB nodes - then the F5 will allow the websockets traffic as passthrough. Also keep in mind that if this is an HTTPS virtual sever that you will need to ensure a client and server side HTTPS profile (SSL offload) are applied to the Virtual Server.

Answer (score 0):

While there are a variety of ways that you can fiddle with load balancers to minimize the downtime caused by a software upgrade, none of them solve the problem, which is that your application-layer protocol seems to not tolerate some small network outages.

Even if you have a perfect load balancer and your software deploys cause zero downtime, the customer's computer may be on flaky wifi which causes a network dropout for half a second - or going over ethernet and someone reconfigures some routing on their LAN, etc.

I'd suggest having your server maintain a queue of messages for clients (up to some size/time limit) so that when a client drops a connection - whether it be due to load balancers/upgrades - or any other reason, it can continue without disruption.